# Unity how to customize console window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, editor

I want to search for some keywords in logs. For this, I want to add some input field inside of console window. I know that I can override unity's custom editors, like transform panel. But I don't have any idea about overriding unity's console window. Is there anyone knows something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize console to some extent (add color to messages)
but as far as I know, you can't change console functionality.

however, you can add custom widgets to Unity Editor and use them to manipulate the console content

here is an example:
https://github.com/kreso22/Unity-3D-Debug-console-with-color./

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Minor typo in the URL, so had to search for the repo.  https://github.com/kreso22/Unity-3D-Debug-console-with-color.  The comment window in stackoverflow doesn't accept a period (.) as the last character of URL, but the correct URL has a dot / period (.) at the end of the URL.